# Infinite buffering in YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube-api

Play any YouTube video .Pause and forward the video, buffering loader shows and the play icon not appearing. End Result : Infinite loading occurs.

Comment: the api might be out of date

Comment: Which api version are you using because, if you are using v2 lot of things have changed in v3.Try update to v3.

Comment: I am using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.1. Downloaded from

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: @ArunChand Did you find out what was causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this really answers the questions, but I was having a similar issue with infinite loading.

Basically I would play a video using a player fragment, exit the video, and then the next video I would try to play would display an infinite loading indicator.

This issue was only happening on certain devices.

Since I was using the latest version of the youtube api, I updated the youtube app on the problematic devices and that seemed to resolve the issue.

Hope this helps.